# How to add a classic printer to Google Cloud Print via Chrome programmatically

Tags: google-chrome, google-cloud-print

I wish to automate the process of adding a classic printer to GCP (Google Cloud Print) via Chrome.

Currently, what I do manually is go to chrome://devices and under classic printers I click "Add Printers", and then select the classic printer from the available devices list and click the button to add that printer to GCP (Instructions taken from here: https://support.google.com/cloudprint/answer/1686197?hl=en)

My questions are:

1. Is there an API with which I can get the list of printers that Chrome detects as candidates to add to GCP?
2. Once I do get the printers list, what API should I use to register the printers with GCP?

Thanks in advance!